# How to use R to retrieve certain characters from multiple places in a string

Tags: r

In my dataset, I have a column contains strings like this:

```
id<-c(1:4)
colstr<-c("<div class="rich-text-field-label"><p>107. <span style="font-weight: normal;">Did the </span>Goodie bag<span style="font-weight: normal;"> encourage you to go back for your month one PrEP refill?</span></p></div>","<div class="rich-text-field-label"><p>110. Have you ever seen the <span style="color: #3598db;">brochure</span> that is contained in the 'Goodie Bag'?</p></div>","<div class="rich-text-field-label"><p>116. <span style="font-weight: normal;">Have you ever used the </span>call-in line<span style="font-weight: normal;"> phone number on the brochure</span>?</p></div>","<div class='box-body'><b><p style="text-transform:uppercase; border:1px solid black;padding:2px;color:blue"><span style="display:block;border:1px solid grey;padding:10px">Review the data entered and make sure there is <i style="color:red">*no missing data*</i>.<br/>Thereafter, click on <i style="color:red">save & exit record</i> to save this interview</span></p></b></div>")

df<-data.frame(id, colstr)
```

For the column: "colstr", if I only want to keep the words outside of `"<xxxx>"`, for example, ideal result like this:

```
id    colstr
1    107. Did the Goodie bag encourage you to go back for your month one PrEP refill?
2    110. Have you ever seen the brochure that is contained in the 'Goodie Bag'? 
....
```

Like the example that I need retrieve a whole sentence from different places of a string cut by irregular , How should I write a code in R and set up a pattern in that code to successfully retrieve the words I want? Thanks a lot~~!

---

Update:
Based on the help below, now the question has been simplified like: How to use either gsub or str_replace to remove all `<xxxx>` in string?

The code `df$colstr<-gsub("</?.*?>", "", df$colstr)`generates error message when I put it into my pipe line, when I use it as  `mutate(colstr=str_replace(df$colstr, "</?.*?>", ""))`, it only removes the `>`in string. Does anyone happen to know how to fix it? Thanks a lot~~!

Comment: Second solution with `rvest` is how I would do it, for what its worth.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, assuming the HTML tags be not nested, would be to simply strip off all opening and closing tags:

```r
df$colstr <- gsub("</?.*?>", "", df$colstr)
```

Comment: @Adam You may mark the question as duplicate in this case.  If you're insinuating that I copied an old answer, well I didn't.  The answers I post to this site are generally freshly baked.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim Biegeleisen, the one challenge here is that when I put this code in my pipeline, R spits out the error message: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, `varible descriptions`, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 515, could you help to see which part might be wrong? Thanks~~~

Answer (score 1):

Your text really looks like HTML code.
Have you looked into the RVest Package?
You could actually read your HTML code and keep all the information. And then when needed extract the text out of the HTML code. This would be a lot cleaner and easier way to do want you want.

an example would be:

```
colstr <- read_html("https://www.youwebsite.html") %>% 
  html_text2()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Léo Henry, I am making a codebook based on this raw data dictionary from provider, I never thought to handle that in this way. Good to learn and will try it~~~Thx :)